# Class instance variable is coming as `nil` in instance method

Tags: ruby, class-instance-variables

I assigned a class instance variable as an array.

```
class Red
  @items = ["brinjal", "banana"]
  puts @items.inspect 
  def test
    puts @items.inspect
  end
end

p = Red.new # => prints ["brinjal", "banana"]
p.test # => prints nil
```

If I access an instance of the class, it returns `nil`. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`["brinjal", "banana"]` is in `@items` of `Red`, a `Class` object.

`nil` is in `@items` of `p`, a `Red` object.

If you change all of your `@` to `@@`, it will work, as those are always class-level. Or you could use a class-level accessor:

```
class Red
  class << self
    attr_accessor :items
  end
  @items=[]
  @items<<"brinjal"
  @items<<"banana"
  puts items.inspect
  def test
    puts self.class.items.inspect
  end
end
```